# merging two c# project-need to insert 1 into the other

Tags: c#

here's the list of projects I have:

[image]

I need to insert the weather and maps into the PL.
I've tried several things and came up empty(I saw what was suggested to people who asked similar question but it didn't work for my situation).
any ideas?it's for a project I make and I need to submit it in a few days.

Comment: Do you mean you want to "Add Reference..."?

Comment: "I need to insert the weather and maps into the PL."  - what do you mean by using this word 'insert' ? You would like to use these projects by adding reference / instantiating classes ? Or something else ?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do ("inserting" a project into another makes little sense), and more importantly, why do you need to do it? We could help you if you were clearer.

Comment: @richard I recently read about a person working at a German city council who answered an email by scanning the printed and hand-commented original mail, putting that picture into a Word document and sending an empty email with only that document attached. **That's** 2015!

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar For full effect it should have been photo of the corrected printout *on a wooden table* of course. :-). And I regularly see screenshots in word docs emailed from clients: sometimes it is hard to see there is too much complexity.

Comment: @Richard Oh yes, the Wooden Table (tm) :-D Actually I get those "Screenshot in a Word Doc" regularly, but mostly because those customers have strict company-wide email filters, which are configured to remove everything but Word docs, so they think they can also only send Word docs...

Answer (score 1):

If you have resharper plugin installed in VS then you can select all the files and folder. Then press F6(or right click selection refactor->move).

Otherwise you would have to move all the files manually by dragging to one project to other.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to merge the code bases, there's no easy way to do that. You'll just have to go one file or folder at a time, update the namespaces, resolve any conflicting names etc.

If you want to just use the functionality within your other projects, you can add a project reference to them from the consuming project. You can do this via References -> Right click -> Add Reference -> Solution Tab -> Tick the projects you want to reference -> Ok

[image]

[image]

Comment: yes i want to merge them,do i need to go file by file and relocate it?

Comment: anyway to add a vb class to a c# class library?

Comment: Ah fiddlesticks, didn't even notice that. No, you can't. And I'm failing to see  a reason for this merge, as it'll just increase your project overhead tremendously. Why not just keep your projects separate and have project references?

Comment: i know,my thoughts exactly. but my instructor said that it should be a part of the PL(you can see it in the image). my project works perfectly fine now with references but i thought there's a way to make one project a part of another..